# How do you represent a conversion factor by using a "const" symbolic constant?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at c++ who has a Python background and I am currently self teaching c++ before school starts so I can get ahead of the game. There's this practice problem that I found and I am about 95% complete, but the last 5% of the instructions in the question is a bit confusing to me. I am particularly stuck at the bolded part of last sentence.

Practice problem:

Write a short program that asks for your height in integer inches and then converts your height to feet and inches. Have the program use the underscore character to indicate where to type the response.**Also use a const symbolic constant to repre-sent the conversion factor.**

My CURRENT work:

```
// simpleheight.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int number, inches, feet;
    cout << "Enter your height in integer inches";
    cin >> number;
    inches = number%12;
    feet = number/12;
    cout << "You are " << feet << " feet" << " and" << inches << " inches" << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As you guys can see, it's nearly done, but I just don't get what the problem wants from me for the bolded sentence. Is it perhaps asking me to do something like this:

```
const int inches = number%12;
const int feet = number/12;
```

If not, can someone guide me through the last 5% of this question :D?

Comment: so like if 12 is the constant then I guess do const int constfactor = 12; and use constfactor like ,  inches = number%constfactor;

Comment: Isn't that a bit too simple? I imagine the last sentence wants something complicated :/. Or is it just me...

Comment: the problem wants you to present 12 as a constant. like `const int factor = 12;` and use like `inches = number % factor; feet = number / factor;`

Comment: @user3720526 the main point the question is trying to teach you is how you can use const do declare variable which doesnot change over the program. It helps check error cause someone might accidently change the const value

Comment: @solti: ITYM "noone can accidentally change the const value".

Comment: @MSalters true ... it will cause compilation error if accidently changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing a quick search you will notice that a symbolic constant is something that cannot be altered. So a const will be fine in this context.

Comment: Darn, I forgot about that important part in my c++ guide. Only thing I remembered until now was that you can also use it to identify values more easily.

Comment: Well, `12` can't be altered either, but that's not a **symbolic** constant. `InchPerFeet` would be a symbol. You have to implement both parts of "symbolic constant".

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this.

```
static const unsigned int FACTOR = 12;
...
inches = number%FACTOR;
feet = number/FACTOR;
```

Comment: I would avoid typing a variable in all caps since that is normally used for preprocessor defines and macros.

Comment: Not much meaning here. But as RedX said I usually avoid to use all caps for usual variables except static const. That's why I added static here.

Comment: `static` is redundant here (namespace-scope consts default to static, and block-scope consts have no need for it)

Answer (score -1):

you should use conversation value of inch to feet.

```
const double incToFeet = 0.08333;
```

and then use that value to convert

Comment: TBH if you start with non-SI units you deserve all the mathematical pain that follows. Just ask NASA.